# What are the odds of matching?

Tags: probability

Sorry, I know this is probably simple but for some reason I can’t get my head around it. Two people each have a 25% chance of making a shot which means they also each have a 75% chance of missing. How do you calculate the total odds of them matching each other with either hits or misses?
Thanks

Comment: How many shoots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem statement correctly, the probability they both hit is $0.25^2$, and the probability they both miss is $0.75^2$ (assuming that whether one person hits/misses is independent of whether the other person hits/misses). Then the total probability that they either both hit or both miss is $0.25^2 + 0.75^2 = 0.625$.

Comment: I kept coming up with that answer but I wasn’t sure if one needed to minus one of them from the other which sometimes gives you the answer of .5

Comment: There is no reason why you would do that.

Comment: I don’t know, something doesn’t seem right. For example if you change my set up to 50% chance of making the shot and 50% chance of missing then according to your reasoning it would be .5 squared +.5 squared equals .5 but we know 1/2x1/2 is actually .25 Could you please take another look at this and explain where I’m getting confused. Thank you

Comment: In that case, the probability they both hit is $1/2 \cdot 1/2 = 1/4$ and the probability they both miss is $1/2 \cdot 1/2 = 1/4$. Adding those gives $1/2$. If you were to do only $1/2 \cdot 1/2$, you would be finding the probability only that they both hit, or only that they both miss, whereas we want either/or.

Comment: what does cdot mean?

Comment: Multiplication.

Comment: sorry for being a pest but I still don’t get it. If each one has a 50% chance of hitting then there’s a 25% chance they will match. If each one has a 50% chance of missing and there’s a 25% chance they will match missing. If you add those together like you did above then you would get 50% chance of matching

Comment: Yes, I claim there would be a $50\%$ chance of matching. You seem to think that isn't right, but are unable to articulate why.

Comment: thanks, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant that $0.25$ is a parameter in Binomial distribution, you have the following outcomes (this also assumes independence events and $n$ repetitions):
$$
P(X=0, Y=0) = \binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{0}(0.75)^{2n} \\
P(X=1, Y=1) = \binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{1}(0.25)^2(0.75)^{2n-2} \\
\ldots\\
P(X=n, Y=n) = \binom{n}{n}\binom{n}{n}(0.25)^{2n} 
$$
In total, $P(S) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} P(X=k,Y=k)$.
Although I'm not sure Binomial sum of the form $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (\binom{n}{k})^2 x^k$ exists in closed form. You can find a good asymptotic approximation for large $n$.

Comment: So what is the final answer?

Comment: It doesn't exist in closed form. Are are allowed to leave the answer as a sum?